# Can not remove(delete) quickblox id

Tags: javascript, node.js, quickblox

When i try to delete a quickbloxid, i am getting an error

**{
   code: 404,
   status: 'error',
   message: '{"code":null,"message":"Possible subdomains: admin, api, billing"}',
   detail: null
}**

I really don't understand what this error message means.

Below is the code that i am using :-

````
   QB.createSession(function(sessionErr: any, result: any) {
     if (sessionErr) {
       resolve({
         status: false,
         data: sessionErr,
       });
     }
     QB.users.delete(userId, function(err: any, result: any){
       console.log(" --> -->", result, err) 
       if (result) {
         resolve({
           status: true,
           data: result,
         });
       } else {
         resolve({
           status: false,
           data: err,
         });
       }
     });
   });```
````